# iOS Programming: Understand UINavigationController and the RootViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, rootview

I'm reading Apple doc but I don't understand what a root controller is. The doc says that this is the controller at the bottom of the stack. Maybe, is this the controller that I've push the first time? Anyone can explain this concept?

From Apple doc [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I've seen that there is a method called initWithRootViewController

> Initializes and returns a newly
>   created navigation controller.
>   - (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController
>   *)rootViewController

What does it mean? Then, is it possible to change the root view controller or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `rootViewController` isn't a type of object, but a property name. It just happens to be the particular `UIViewController` instance at the bottom of the stack, as Nubbel said.

Methods like `initWithRootViewController` are for situations when you want to initialize `UINavigationController`, and also tell it to "use this VC as the first VC in the heirarchy".

It seems like `UINavigationController` really doesn't want you to change that property after it's been created, but [it looks like ppl have found ways to do it](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller%E2%80%99s-root-view-controller/):  - Remember to check the comments to see if this is an "approved" method of working.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the Docs and you already said, it is the controller at the bottom of the stack, the first controller pushed to the stack. Subsequent controllers will be pushed on top of the RootViewController. To return to the RootViewController you can use the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`method.
Furthermore, you can't change the RootViewController!

Comment: Thank you nubbel. what about initWithRootViewController?